# Push Notification is not displayed in device

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on an `Android` project. In my project I have to implement `push notification`. I followed the tutorial from [androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Project is working without any error. But when I am trying to send message from local-server to device , I am not getting any notifications.

`registerid` in db and `GCMregister` is same... nothing happening when sending message...Is that the problem of server side?

I tested with several emulater.

please help me to solve my issue.

Comment: Your device is support gcm service?

Comment: Is onMessage() called?

Comment: @Yahor10...support gcm service..what that means?..how can I test?

Comment: @Ascorbin....onMessage() is not calling....what I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Need to check:
--Check your registration id is stored in your database or not?And you are using same id or not?
--on client side ,check whether it is register in GCMRegistrar **isRegisteredOnServer()**?
--During sending message chck 
 --'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY, //specify server or browser key obtained from google console.
 --Proper registration Id
```

Comment: registeration id stored in db  and GCMRegister is same.About  Authorization: key I have tested with both server key and browser key..no change... Proper registeration id...??...how can I  check that?

Comment: whenever you register your device into GCMRegistrar at that time  onRegister() method of GCMIntentService will be called.Get reg id from here.
Use this reg id and try to send msg to this.hard code reg id during send message code.
post me if you get any message or not

Comment: @mahesh...registerid in db and GCMregister is same.. I hardcoded that regid in sendmessage code... but nothing happened... I check the logcat.. nothing happening when sendingmessage...Is that the problem of server side?

Comment: if you find everything ok then check  server side..
is sendMessage code actually working or not..
Otherwise create seperate project and write only send message method in that.run that project..
hope this will work for you.

Comment: Also add your code if possible so that we can rectify your problem

Comment: I reinstall wamp..but its not working...I tried to track the server side...and I got an error in server side.."Call to undefined function curl_init()  in gcm server GCM.php"....i already checked the curl..but not working

Comment: provide some code sarath. now without code i not able to figure out your exact problem.

Comment: Mahesh...http://download.androidhive.info/download?code=iS5bX74qeLC9BJzKIwhYnSHv0vziNeO5we85USk3IGtj6%2Faczubg6fCH0vmiw9zHaMdsR5SffC%2Fre3MUd93rM%2Blp8F6fqJjFS%2B%2FniItFlnA551qjzzUItsLnCQCb%2Fzs0N8P%2FUOajn7DlOMPdl89grMIWwlyHPNtyzcfvHOlovZ8nAeR51mOro7aUYBA51MKIvxruyT....I am using the same code from the above link...can u try this?

Answer (score 0):

please also check your device having an account of google for
 that you have to go following step:

1. go to setting menu--> account&sync-->add account-->google-->next-->create an account or signin-->finish.

then you can perform your application correctly.

now only one thing is remaining after viewing your all comments please check your php code in that when i first learn at that time in google api key and db name and password having some problem so check it out.

Answer (score -1):

create a new AVD and select any GoogleAPI as target like this

[image]

Comment: Actually I am working with google apli target api version 8...So thats not the reason